# Why would the subjunctive be used when the indicative seems to be required?

Tags: conjunctive

In the following passage from Fabulae Faciles:

> Amāzonēs impetum virōrum fortissimē sustinuērunt, et contrā opīniōnem
> omnium tantam virtūtem praestitērunt ut multōs eōrum occīderint,
> multōs etiam in fugam coniēcerint. Virī enim novō genere pugnae
> perturbābantur nec magnam virtūtem praestābant.
> **Herculēs autem cum haec vidēret, de suīs fortūnīs dēspērāre coepit.**

Why would the subjunctive (videret) be used? The last sentence seems to read "However, when Hercules saw these (things), he began to despair of his fortunes." So, if that is right, shouldn't it just be vidit (saw), not videret?

Also, why haec? Shouldn't these things be *haes*, not haec? Haec is the neuter nominative, not accusative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Latin, *cum* is a standard way to introduce a dependent clause. These *cum* clauses can indicate circumstance ("when he saw it"), cause ("because he saw it"), or adversity ("even though he saw it"); the exact translation depends on context.

And notably, **finite verbs in these subordinate clauses are almost always subjunctive**. This is actually how the subjunctive mood gets its name: these clauses and the verbs in them are subordinated to (*subjunctus*) the main clause.

For your second question, I'm not sure where you're getting "haes" from—neuter forms, as a rule, look exactly the same in the nominative and the accusative, for reasons going back to Proto-Indo-European. So *haec* is the neuter plural accusative as well as nominative.

Comment: This is the table where haes is given as the neuter plural accusative: https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-dictionary-flexion.php?lemma=HIC200  Is this web site just wrong?

Comment: @TylerDurden Yep. _Haec_ is standard; I checked to make sure there wasn't some obscure variant form, and a corpus search shows no attestations of "haes".

Comment: Right. And when the verb after *cum* is in the indicative, you know the subordinate clause is *independent*, indicating the events happened at the same time, but *independent* of each other, e.g. *Eo tempore cum Romae vivebam, Colosseum etiam stabat.*

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes, that is a terrible site. You can find reliable tables at Wiktionary and Collatinus-web, for example. I mean seriously. This is like somebody creating the website "Online English Dictionary" and claiming the demonstrative pronouns are "this" and "thut".

Comment: @Sebastian brings to mind the [Scottish wikipedia fake](https://www.reddit.com/r/Scotland/comments/ig9jia/ive_discovered_that_almost_every_single_article/) by some teenager who had no deeper knowledge of Scottish than me. Maybe he switched languages after getting exposed?? Still an amazing feat -- like the guy who fixed one of the car wrecks on my mother-in-law's Texas farm only in order to steal it. You would want to give them a legit job putting their commitment and skill to better use.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel To be fair, the site seems to incorporate a decent morphological analyzer, so I'm more inclined to blame this on poor proofreading than poor language knowledge. Someone who didn't know Latin wouldn't be able to implement such a thing.

Comment: @Draconis It even (correctly) lists obscure alternative forms like *queis* for *quibus*. So I agree, the site was probably not made by ignoramuses, and maybe it's as simple as a typo. But it sure is an embarrassing mistake.